# convert a Pseudocode into c# code

Tags: c#, pseudocode

i have a very simple question,how can i convert and use this Pseudocode in c# code?

```
repeat
 i=i+1;
 until x[i]>=j
```

i mean what code in c# does the same work of this  code?thanks

Comment: First you will need to define a non-pseudo `x[]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use a [do/while](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx) loop:

```
do {
    i++;
} while (x[i] < j);
```

Answer (score 2):

Also:

```
do {} while (x[++i] < j);
```

(Purely as a stylistic alternative)

Comment: Oh, so it is! Learn something new every day... :)